# Regex one liner to extract pattern matching groups

Tags: java, regex, java-stream

Using Java 11 I wonder how I can use the Stream API to extract all the group matches to a list of strings in a one-liner.

Given this regexp and string:

```
String regexp = "(\\d\\d\\d)-(\\d)-(\\d\\d)";
String str = "123-8-90";
```

I know how to obtain the result in multiple lines:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
if (matcher.find()) {
  matches.add(matcher.group(1));
  matches.add(matcher.group(2));
  matches.add(matcher.group(3));
}

System.out.println(matches);
```

This prints the expected list of 3 distinct numeric strings: **[123, 8, 90]**

My attempt to achieve the same in one liner:

```
List<String> matches = Pattern.compile(regexp)
    .matcher(str)
    .results()
    .map(MatchResult::group)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(matches);
```

This prints the unexpected: **[123-8-90]**

**How can I use the MatchResult::group(int) method in the stream?**

Comment: Replace `.map(MatchResult::group)` with `.flatMap(mr -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, mr.groupCount()).mapToObj(mr::group))`

Comment: You should add this as the answer.

Comment: Or change the pattern to `"\\d+"`. Then, `Pattern.compile("\\d+") .matcher(str) .results() .map(MatchResult::group) .collect(Collectors.toList())` will work. Or just use `List<String> matches = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\D+"));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were pretty close. You need to flat map the `MatchResult#group`:

```
List<String> matches = Pattern.compile(regexp)
    .matcher(str)
    .results()
    .flatMap(mr -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, mr.groupCount())
        .mapToObj(mr::group))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your unnecessarily complex regex has made your solution error-prone and complicated. A couple of the easier ways to do it can be:

1. Use the regex, `\d+` and map the `Stream` to `MatchResult::group`.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> matches = 
                Pattern.compile("\\d+")
                        .matcher("123-8-90")
                        .results()
                        .map(MatchResult::group)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(matches);// [123, 8, 90]
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/PvoxAK)

2. Split on `-`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> matches = Arrays.asList("123-8-90".split("-"));
        System.out.println(matches);// [123, 8, 90]
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/0hfxwk)

In addition to solutions using regex, the characters of the string can be traversed and the numbers can be collected into a `List`. As with regex solutions, there can be many ways to do this as well.